# Internet Explorer shows strange node value of text node after using back button

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, jsonp

This is a problem in Internet Explorer 7 and 8 which only seems to be happening when the code that is accessing the node value is triggered via JSONP:

**test.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<span>testing</span>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.attachEvent('onload', function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'test.js');
    script.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
    head[0].appendChild(script);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
alert(document.body.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

When loading the page the first time the alert says "testing" as expected. However, after pressing the link and then using the browser back button the alert suddenly says "��testi" instead.

Why is this and what would be an appropriate work-around?

Comment: Instead, what do you expect for the result? HTMLSpanElement element or the innerHTML 'testing'?

Comment: I expect the text node value which should be "testing". It's not the same thing as innerHTML even though both should yield the same output in this case.

Comment: I can understand you expect the text node value. But document.body.childNodes[0] may not return a element node but a text node.

Comment: See my answer. Use 'document.body.children[0]' to find the first element node.

Answer (score 0):

test.html part is fine.

```
<html>
<body>
<span>testing</span>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.attachEvent('onload', function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'test.js');
    script.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
    head[0].appendChild(script);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js should be

```
alert(document.body.children[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

Comment: I understand that you've tested this out, but do you know why it impacts the encoding like that?

Comment: No.. I am answering "what would be an appropriate work-around"..I cannot figure out why.